# Cannot push image to OCR container repository - unknown: Tenant with namespace - not found

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to push an image to OCR within my 'training' compartment but docker returns with message: "unknown: Tenant with namespace training not found"

The compartment is there:

```
oci iam compartment list --all --output table --compartment-id-in-subtree true --query "data [?\"lifecycle-state\" =='ACTIVE'].{Name:name}" | grep training
| training                  |
```

Create repository 'ocr1'

```
export DISPLAY_NAME=ocr1
oci artifacts container repository create \
  --compartment-id $C \
  --is-public false \
  --display-name $DISPLAY_NAME
```

Docker login

```
cat token | docker login fra.ocir.io --username=${NS}/api.user --password-stdin
Login Succeeded
```

Tag image and push

```
docker pull alpine:latest
docker tag alpine:latest fra.ocir.io/training/ocr1/alpine:latest
docker push fra.ocir.io/training/ocr1/alpine:latest
The push refers to repository [fra.ocir.io/training/ocr1/alpine]
7cd52847ad77: Retrying in 1 second
unknown: Tenant with namespace training not found
```

I am only able to push to root compartment ... (not what I want)

```
docker tag alpine:latest fra.ocir.io/$NS/ocr1/alpine:latest
docker push fra.ocir.io/$NS/ocr1/alpine:latest
The push refers to repository [fra.ocir.io/<NS>/ocr1/alpine]
7cd52847ad77: Layer already exists
latest: digest: sha256:e2e16842c9b54d985bf1ef9242a313f36b856181f188de21313820e177002501 size: 528
```

Why can't I push to a given compartment?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you may be experiencing a permissions issue. Admins have more permissions in root than in a net new compartment where you need to specify access policies. Is this doc helpful?
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Registry/Concepts/registrypolicyrepoaccess.htm